# Call a function outside any method but inside a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to call a function to initialize my <strike>global</strike> class-level variables. Note that for some reason, I cannot write a constructor to do the job. *(reason: I'm writing a test case for Tempest)*

Code:

```
class my_class(ParentClass):
    username = "abc"
    password = "123"
    hostname = self._get_hostname() # Error: self is undefined
    hostname = _get_hostname()      # Error: _get_hostname is undefined

    def myFunct(self):
        ...
        ...

    def _get_hostname(self):
        ...
        ...
```

Is it even possible in python to initialize <strike>global</strike> class-level variables with class functions?

**Note 1:** I have also tried to perform `hostname` initialization after the `_get_hostname()` function is written, but of no use.

**Note 2:** I can perform `hostname` initialization within a function such as:

```
def myFunction(self):
    hostname = self._get_hostname()
    # do something with hostname
    ...
```

But that would defeat the whole purpose of using a <strike>global</strike> class-level variable. I want to use a class-level variable for **re-usage** in other functions.

Comment: use `def __init__(self):` for the constructor, the code after the Class definition you've got isn't a constructor.

Comment: @xthestreams dear I already mentioned that I **can't write a constructor**.

Comment: @InamTaj why don't you make `_get_hostname(cls):` a class method then like using `@classmethod` decorator?

Comment: There is no case for setting global variables in a class definition.  The code in a class definition is evaluated when its module is loaded, so trying to set variables there is as effective as defining them outside the class on the module level.

Comment: @Serdmanczyk I was wrong calling them global. What I meant was **class-level** variables. I've edited my question.

Comment: @InamTaj ah, then what you're doing is correct for defining them, but you don't have `self` (idiomatically an instance of the class) yet at that spot which is why you're having trouble with self._get_hostname().  @chepner has good advice in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

First: they are not global variables; they are *class* variables. (Globals are defined at the module scope.)

If `_get_hostname()` doesn't actually *use* `self` at all, you can do something a little sketchy: make sure it is defined *before* you use it, then call it with a fake first argument.

```
class my_class(ParentClass):
    def _get_hostname(self):
        ...
    hostname = _get_hostname(None)   # Doesn't matter what
```

This works because when you call it inside the `class` statement, you can still treat it as a regular function. It just has to be defined before you use it, like any function.

If it actually does require a reference to an object (or even just the class), this won't work, because the class doesn't exist yet. The best you can do is either define a function prior to the `class` statement that doesn't use the class itself and call it. (This is also what you would do
if the previous option was possible but ... distasteful.)

```
def _get_hostname():
    ...

class my_class(ParentClass):
    hostname = _get_hostname()
```

or defer initializing the class variable until after the `class` is defined. In this case, `_get_hostname` should probably be declared as a static method or a class method so that you don't have to instantiate the class just to initialize the class variable.

```
class my_class(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def _get_hostname1(cls):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def _get_hostname2():
        ...

my_class.hostname = my_class._get_hostname1()
my_class.hostname = my_class._get_hostname2()
```

Comment: That is very un-pythonic, there is a reason there is an @staticmethod decorator

Comment: I have no idea what `_get_hostname1` actually does, which is why I mention the possibility of making it a `classmethod`. I would strongly recommend the regular function defined prior to the class if that is feasible.

Comment: I've made the correction of class-level variable instead of global. I was wrong calling them global.

Comment: Same problem occurs for `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` approach.

Comment: You haven't said what problem you get.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call instance methods for an instance that doesn't exist yet. If you want for it to be independent of any instance, and the functions you call don't require any information from the instance, you can use an @staticmethod decorator so you can call get hostname statically.

Comment: Same problem occurs for `@staticmethod` approach when I try to perform intialization. This is what I'm doing. `hostname = my_class._get_hostname()`

Comment: It should just be _get_hostname() unless I'm mistaken, and additionally it shouldn't take a self parameter